# Problems in defining an applicative instance

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, type-level-computation

Suppose that I'm wanting to define a data-type indexed by two type level environments. Something like:

```
data Woo s a = Woo a | Waa s a

data Foo (s :: *) (env :: [(Symbol,*)]) (env' :: [(Symbol,*)]) (a :: *) =
     Foo { runFoo :: s -> Sing env -> (Woo s a, Sing env') }
```

The idea is that `env` is the input environment and `env'` is the output one. So, type `Foo` acts like an [indexed state monad](https://gist.github.com/pthariensflame/5054294). So far, so good. My problem is how could I show that `Foo` is an applicative functor. The obvious try is

```
instance Applicative (Foo s env env') where
    pure x = Foo (\s env -> (Woo x, env))
    -- definition of (<*>) omitted.
```

but GHC complains that `pure` is ill-typed since it infers the type

```
    pure :: a -> Foo s env env a
```

instead of the expected type

```
    pure :: a -> Foo s env env' a
```

what is completely reasonable. My point is, it is possible to define an `Applicative` instance for `Foo` allowing to change the environment type? I googled for [indexed functors](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjowLqr1KzNAhUGkJAKHZ8aDc0QPAgD#hl=pt-BR&q=indexed%20applicative%20functor), but at first sight, they don't appear to solve my problem. Can someone suggest something to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Foo` type is an example of what Atkey originally called a [*parameterised monad*](http://bentnib.org/paramnotions-jfp.pdf), and everyone else (arguably incorrectly) now calls an *indexed monad*.

Indexed monads are monad-like things with two indices which describe a path through a directed graph of types. Sequencing indexed monadic computations requires that the indices of the two computations line up like dominos.

```
class IFunctor f where
    imap :: (a -> b) -> f x y a -> f x y b

class IFunctor f => IApplicative f where
    ipure :: a -> f x x a
    (<**>) :: f x y (a -> b) -> f y z a -> f x z b

class IApplicative m => IMonad m where
    (>>>=) :: m x y a -> (a -> m y z b) -> m x z b
```

If you have an indexed monad which describes a path from `x` to `y`, and a way to get from `y` to `z`, the indexed bind `>>>=` will give you a bigger computation which takes you from `x` to `z`.

Note also that `ipure` returns `f x x a`. The value returned by `ipure` doesn't take any steps through the directed graph of types. Like a type-level `id`.

A simple example of an indexed monad, to which you alluded in your question, is the indexed state monad `newtype IState i o a = IState (i -> (o, a))`, which transforms the type of its argument from `i` to `o`. You can only sequence stateful computations if the output type of the first matches the input type of the second.

```
newtype IState i o a = IState { runIState :: i -> (o, a) }

instance IFunctor IState where
    imap f s = IState $ \i ->
        let (o, x) = runIState s i
        in (o, f x)

instance IApplicative IState where
    ipure x = IState $ \s -> (s, x)
    sf <**> sx = IState $ \i ->
        let (s, f) = runIState sf i
            (o, x) = runIState sx s
        in (o, f x)

instance IMonad IState where
    s >>>= f = IState $ \i ->
        let (t, x) = runIState s i
        in runIState (f x) t
```

---

Now, to your actual question. `IMonad`, with its domino-esque sequencing, is a good abstraction for computations which transform a type-level environment: you expect the first computation to leave the environment in a state which is palatable to the second. Let us write an instance of `IMonad` for `Foo`.

I'm going to start by noting that your `Woo s a` type is isomorphic to `(a, Maybe s)`, which is an example of the [`Writer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Lazy.html#t:Writer) monad. I mention this because we'll need an instance for `Monad (Woo s)` later and I'm too lazy to write my own.

```
type Woo s a = Writer (First s) a
```

I've picked [`First`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:First) as my preferred flavour of `Maybe` monoid but I don't know exactly how you intend to use `Woo`. You may prefer [`Last`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Last).

I'm also soon going to make use of the fact that `Writer` is an instance of [`Traversable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html). In fact, `Writer` is even more traversable than that: because it contains exactly one `a`, we won't need to smash any results together. This means we only need a `Functor` constraint for the effectful `f`.

```
-- cf. traverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
traverseW :: Functor f => (a -> f b) -> Writer w a -> f (Writer w b)
traverseW f m = let (x, w) = runWriter m
                in fmap (\x -> writer (x, w)) (f x)
```

Let's get down to business.

`Foo s` is an `IFunctor`. The instance makes use of `Writer s`'s functor-ness: we go inside the stateful computation and `fmap` the function over the `Writer` monad inside.

```
newtype Foo (s :: *) (env :: [(Symbol,*)]) (env' :: [(Symbol,*)]) (a :: *) =
    Foo { runFoo :: s -> Sing env -> (Woo s a, Sing env') }

instance IFunctor (Foo s) where
    imap f foo = Foo $ \s env ->
        let (woo, env') = runFoo foo s env
        in (fmap f woo, env')
```

We'll also need to make `Foo` a regular `Functor`, to use it with `traverseW` later.

```
instance Functor (Foo s x y) where
    fmap = imap
```

`Foo s` is an `IApplicative`. We have to use `Writer s`'s `Applicative` instance to smash the `Woo`s together. This is where the `Monoid s` constraint comes from.

```
instance IApplicative (Foo s) where
    ipure x = Foo $ \s env -> (pure x, env)
    foo <**> bar = Foo $ \s env ->
        let (woof, env') = runFoo foo s env
            (woox, env'') = runFoo bar s env'
        in (woof <*> woox, env'')
```

`Foo s` is an `IMonad`. Surprise surprise, we end up delegating to `Writer s`'s `Monad` instance. Note also the crafty use of `traverseW` to feed the intermediate `a` inside the writer to the Kleisli arrow `f`.

```
instance IMonad (Foo s) where
    foo >>>= f = Foo $ \s env ->
        let (woo, env') = runFoo foo s env
            (woowoo, env'') = runFoo (traverseW f woo) s env'
        in (join woowoo, env'')
```

---

**Addendum**: The thing that's missing from this picture is transformers. Instinct tells me that you should be able to express `Foo` as a monad transformer stack:

```
type Foo s env env' = ReaderT s (IStateT (Sing env) (Sing env') (WriterT (First s) Identity))
```

But indexed monads don't have a compelling story to tell about transformers. The type of `>>>=` would require all the indexed monads in the stack to manipulate their indices in the same way, which is probably not what you want. Indexed monads also don't compose nicely with regular monads.

All this is to say that indexed monad transformers play out a bit nicer with a [McBride-style indexing scheme](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/Kleisli.pdf). McBride's `IMonad` looks like this:

```
type f ~> g = forall x. f x -> g x

class IMonad m where
    ireturn :: a ~> m a
    (=<?) :: (a ~> m b) -> (m a ~> m b)
```

Then monad transformers would look like this:

```
class IMonadTrans t where
    ilift :: IMonad m => m a ~> t m a
```

Comment: I think this is another good answer; it all depends on OP's plans for the `Foo` type.  Out of curiosity, do you know of anyone who plays with a parallelized indexed applicative with `parAp :: f w x (a -> b) -> f y z a -> f (w,y) (x,z) b`?

Comment: Your `parAp` is isomorphic to `f i (a -> b) -> f j a -> f (i ++ j) b` when you set `i ~ '[w, x]` and `j ~ '[y, z]`. That type looks like `ap` for [Orchard's version of indexed monads](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~dao29/ixmonad/ixmonad-fita14.pdf). He uses a type-level monoid to join up indices.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you're missing a constraint on `Sing env'` - namely that it needs to be a `Monoid`, because:

- you need to be able to generate a value of type `Sing env'` from nothing (e.g. `mempty`)
- you need to be able to combine two values of type `Sing env'` into one during `<*>` (e.g. `mappend`).

You'll also need to the ability combine `s` values in `<*>`, so, unless you want to import `SemiGroup` from somewhere, you'll probably want that to be a `Monoid` too.

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
module SO37860911 where
import GHC.TypeLits (Symbol)
import Data.Singletons (Sing)

data Woo s a = Woo a | Waa s a 
  deriving Functor

instance Monoid s => Applicative (Woo s) where
  pure = Woo 
  Woo f <*> Woo a = Woo $ f a 
  Waa s f <*> Woo a = Waa s $ f a 
  Woo f <*> Waa s a = Waa s $ f a 
  Waa s f <*> Waa s' a = Waa (mappend s s') $ f a 

data Foo (s :: *) (env :: [(Symbol,*)]) (env' :: [(Symbol,*)]) (a :: *) =
     Foo { runFoo :: s -> Sing env -> (Woo s a, Sing env') }
  deriving Functor

instance (Monoid s, Monoid (Sing env')) => Applicative (Foo s env env') where
  pure a = Foo $ \_s _env -> (pure a, mempty)
  Foo mf <*> Foo ma = Foo $ \s env -> case (mf s env, ma s env) of
    ((w,e), (w',e')) -> (w <*> w', e `mappend` e')
```

Comment: I don't think adding `Monoid` constraints willy-nilly is the right way to go. `Foo` treats the singleton environment as an (indexed) `State` monad would, in that it appears in both input and output positions, not like a `Writer` monad. I'll add my own answer.